# Why can't I bind a const lvalue reference to a function returning T&&?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I was binding some return value of a function to a const lvalue reference, but the object was deleted, before the lifetime of the const lvalue reference ended.

In the following example the Foo object is destroyed before the lifetime of `foo` ends:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo destroyed: " << name << std::endl;
    }
    std::string name;
};

Foo&& pass_through(Foo&& foo)
{
    return std::move(foo);
}

int main()
{
    const Foo& foo = pass_through({"some string"});
    std::cout << "before scope end" << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

> Foo destroyed: some string
>   before scope end

live on coliru: [1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e771c4efa77ed6a)

I thought you can bind `const T&` to anything. Is it bad practice to return `T&&` and should returning by value be preferred?

I stumbled across this in the cpprestsdk here:

```
inline utility::string_t&& to_string_t(std::string &&s) { return std::move(s); }
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/include/cpprest/asyncrt_utils.h#L109

Very confusing, because the windows version of `to_string_t` (dispatched by preprocessor macros) **returned by value**:

```
_ASYNCRTIMP utility::string_t __cdecl to_string_t(std::string &&s);
```

Edit:
Why does it work when passing the result of `pass_through` to a function taking `const Foo&`? The lifetime is extended in this case?

Comment: too early in the morning to think, but the explicit destructor may prevent the move constructor from being implicitly created. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor

Comment: Lifetime extension only applies when the reference binds directly to a temporary.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I tried with explicitly generating the default move constructor via `Foo(Foo&&) = default;` and it produced the same result.

Comment: Why would the lifetime of a foo-reference exceed the line const Foo& foo = pass_through({"some string"}); ?

Comment: Imagine if you only had the declaration of `pass_through()` available. There's no way to know there's a link between the parameter RValue ref and the result RValue ref, and the lifetime of the temporary `Foo` must still be resolved at **compile time**, so the compiler has no choice but to be pessimistic about it.

Comment: You can pass it as an argument because the lifetime of a temporary lasts until the end of the "full-expression" it's created in. (Very informally, "until the next semicolon".) No extension is necessary.

Comment: @Pi -- in `const Foo& foo = Foo():` the lifetime of the temporary object created by `Foo()` is extended, so it remains valid as long as `foo` does. That's called "lifetime extension". This question involves creating a temporary `Foo` object indirectly, and, as comments have said, that doesn't result in lifetime extension.

Comment: Static analysis ought to be able to detect this, I predict we will see compilers able to warn about this in future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the standard:

> **15.2 Temporary objects**
>
> ```
> 6.9 A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call persists 
>     until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.
> ```

Essentially what it's saying is that because you passed in a temporary object and then didn't extend its lifetime (say, by moving it into an lvalue) then its lifetime only lasts until the first `;` after the call to `pass_through` in your code. After this point you are left with `foo` as a dangling reference.

```
int main()
{
    const Foo& foo = pass_through({"some string"}); // "some string" lifetime ends here
    std::cout << "before scope end" << std::endl;
}
```

As to whether it is good practice to to return an rvalue reference I believe these two answers already go into detail on the subject:

[Should I return an rvalue reference parameter by rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094067/should-i-return-an-rvalue-reference-parameter-by-rvalue-reference)

[Is returning by rvalue reference more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116641/is-returning-by-rvalue-reference-more-efficient)