# returning a rvalue parameter as a rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters, reference, rvalue

On this thread ([Should I return an rvalue reference parameter by rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094067/should-i-return-an-rvalue-reference-parameter-by-rvalue-reference)), it is written that `The parameter cannot be a temporary (which is just what rvalue references represent)`.
If I understand this sentence well, this code should not be correct

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
std::string &&f(std::string &&a) {
    return std::move(a);   
}

int main() {
    std::string a = f("lol");
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, when we look to `std::get`, it seems that it returns rvalue reference for temporary tuple, and I actually think that there is no issue with using `std::get` with temporary tuple.

So, I think I misunderstand the sentence above, and the prior code is correct. However, this one is not correct :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
std::string &&f(std::string &&a) {
    return std::move(a);   
}

int main() {
    std::string &&a = f("lol");
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It would be correct if the function returns a value and not rvalue reference. Am I correct?

Comment: The first code is correct because the temporary lasts until the end of the statement, and it is not accessed after that (`a` is constructed from it).  The second code is UB because in `cout << a`, `a` refers to a temporary destroyed at the end of the first statement. It would be correct if `f` returned by value, since then the temporary that initializes `a` would be extended to match the lifetime of `a`.

Comment: There are infrequently times where this makes sense to do, but they are VERY few and far between.   You virtually never want to do a `return std::move(...);`  The only semi-common time I've ever found is when you build an object via rvalue-qualified methods: `MyType().set_prop(1).set_prop(2);`